# Electron, Javascript Error occurred in the main process

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm creating an app and every time I open it, it gives me this error:

> Uncaught Exception: TypeError: app.whenReady is not a function at
> Object.
> (/Users/Jaime/Desktop/typing-speed-WPM/stt/main.js:16:5) at
> Module._compile (module.js:541:32) at Object.Module._extensions..js
> (module.js:550:10) at Module.load (module.js:456:32) at tryModuleLoad
> (module.js:415:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3) at
> loadApplicationPackage
> (/Users/Jaime/Desktop/typing-speed-WPM/stt/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar/main.js:293:12)
> at Object.
> (/Users/Jaime/Desktop/typing-speed-WPM/stt/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar/main.js:334:5)
> at Module._compile (module.js:541:32) at Object.Module._extensions..js
> (module.js:550:10)

Comment: try this app.on('ready', createWindow);

Comment: Can you share how your "app" variable is created ? Or may be app variable is assigned.